# Which Visual Studio Code extension is automatically creating "style.js" file?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

I recently switched to VS Code from Sublime and then went on installing some extensions. Upon restart, I noticed that a "style.js" file is being created in the project folder (automatically). But, since I installed a lot of extensions, I cannot remember which extension is creating this file "automagically". The style.js starts with "import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';" but I couldn't find it by "react" or "react-native" keyword (both in program and on web). Does anyone know which extension it is? Thank you in advance.

Comment: My reputation is not high enough to upvote, Steve.

Answer (score 1):

The way to figure it out, is to your extensions, disable all of them. Next, enable one by one, and see if which one causes it.

Good luck!